# Plotting basic uniform distribution on python

Tags: python-2.7

I am a real beginner concerning coding and would like to know how to plot a uniform distribution between two points using python. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Apologies i wrote normal in the title of this question but i meant uniform.

Comment: you can easily edit your question

Comment: I recommend finding a `matplotlib` tutorial for the plotting part; [`numpy.random`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) can help with distribution modelling. But first of all, some general Python tutorial to get a hold of basic concepts/practices.

Comment: @Victoria There is also R language which is quite simple, designed for tasks like that. It includes also some Python frameworks that might interest you.

Answer (score 3):

This will do the work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.uniform(0,1,1000) # You are generating 1000 points between 0 and 1.
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(data, 20, facecolor='green') 

plt.xlabel('X~U[0,1]')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title("Uniform Distribution Histogram (Bin size 20)")
plt.axis([0, 1, 0, 100]) # x_start, x_end, y_start, y_end
plt.grid(True)

plt.show(block = False)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use `numpy.random.uniform(low=initial,high=final,size=size)` for this type of distribution.
Initial and final are your parameters that define the limits of your distribution. You can specify the size of the distribution you want to generate also as a parameter within the function.
 Hope that helps!

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
array = numpy.random.uniform(low=0,high=5,size=100)
plt.plot(array)
plt.show()
```

[image: Image of Random Uniform Distribution drawn between range 0-5, with a sample size of 100]

Comment: the x and y axes need to be swapped here